# How to publish a game that requires native libraries on the Ubuntu Sofware Center

Tags: software-center, 64-bit, package-management, 32-bit

Very recently I published a proprietary game on the Ubuntu Software Center. I uploaded a Debian package containing the binary files. Since the game is written in Java I used 'any' architecture in the Debian control file.

Now I have an update ready that should fix some minor bugs and improve the overall quality. The only problem I have is that it requires a native library. There is a version for 32 bit and 64 bit and the application automatically chooses the correct library. It is needed for gamepad support (jinput). If I enter "any" as architecture in the control file, it displays a warning as soon as I install the application. Do I need to create two separate Debian packages? And if this is needed, how can I submit this update?

My own ideas for this are:

- I could upload a zip file containing both Debian packages, but I do not want to cause the reviewers extra work. Both packages contain almost the same content, since the 64 bit package also requires the 32 bit native libraries in some cases.
- Maybe there is a way to create a single Debian package that will install on both 64 bit and 32 bit Ubuntu versions without warning?

Please let me know if this is not the correct place to ask this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to submit for review through MyApps is to submit a tarball or include your packaging source. The reviewers have to un-ar your binary deb and recreate it using the data.tar.gz so in reality submitting a binary deb does create more work. The packaging team will figure out what is needed to make your application build and run properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My application just got approved by the reviewers. The review process took just 2 days! Very good response time for the reviewers! I did create 2 seperate debian files and uploaded them in a tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

I just uploaded an archive containing 2 debian packages. One debian package for the 32bit version and one for the 64bit version. I will post the result later as soon as I get feedback from the reviewers.

Comment: Don't write a clarification of the main post in a new answer. Edit the question with that information.